AWS Lambda NodeJS Creating Presigned URL POST
I wanted to create a lambda function in AWS to create a presigned url for my project, I am not sure if this is the expected result.
This is the lambda function in AWS console.
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');


AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'xxx',
  secretAccessKey: 'xxx'
});

const bucket = new AWS.S3();


exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // TODO implement
  // let requestObject = event["body"];
  const fileName = event["fileName"];

  // generate a 10 (60 sec. * 10) minutes URL
  const params = {
        Bucket: "xxx",
        Expires: 60 * 60, // in seconds,
        Fields: {
            key: fileName,
        },
        Conditions: [
            ['content-length-range', 0,1073741824]
        ]
    };
    
  const { url, fields } = await bucket.createPresignedPost(params);
  
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    url: url,
    fields: fields
  };
  return response;
};


this is the result of the test request to lambda function
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "url": "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx",
  "fields": {
    "key": "upload/yasin-test-aaa.mp4",
    "bucket": "xxx",
    "X-Amz-Algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
    "X-Amz-Credential": "AKIA4VX7VVP3LMLE3CHF/20240520/eu-west-2/s3/aws4_request",
    "X-Amz-Date": "20240520T173547Z",
    "Policy": "eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAyNC0wNS0yMFQxODozNTo0N1oiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbWyJjb250ZW50LWxlbmd0aC1yYW5nZSIsMCwxMDczNzQxODI0XSx7ImtleSI6InVwbG9hZC95b3J1bS1yZXNpbWxlcmkveWFzaW4tdGVzdC1hYWEubXA0In0seyJidWNrZXQiOiJjZG4udG9uem8uY29tLnRyIn0seyJYLUFtei1BbGdvcml0aG0iOiJBV1M0LUhNQUMtU0hBMjU2In0seyJYLUFtei1DcmVkZW50aWFsIjoiQUtJQTRWWDdWVlAzTE1MRTNDSEYvMjAyNDA1MjAvZXUtd2VzdC0yL3MzL2F3czRfcmVxdWVzdCJ9LHsiWC1BbXotRGF0ZSI6IjIwMjQwNTIwVDE3MzU0N1oifV19",
    "X-Amz-Signature": "3a8372b714f7327de2aef6076210660f51180b077fc960ae7a7179449529d52e"
  }
}

But where is the url to post the file ? I could not locate that from the result? I hope someone can help me on this.

Using bucket as the name of your S3 client (in bucket = new AWS.S3()) is very misleading. Better to name it s3 or s3client or similar.

I'd expect the resulting pre-signed URL to be in url (that you've redacted to https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xx).
